# How to create pointer to different instantiation of template class

Tags: c++, pointers, abstract-factory

In making my first experiments with Abstract Factory in C++(while reading Modern C++ Design - A. Alexandrescu - part 9) i have a question.
If classes hierarchy looks like this:

```
struct B {}; 

struct D1 :public B {};
struct DD1 : public D1 {};
struct DD2 : public D1 {};

struct D2 :public B {};
struct DD3 : public D2 {};
struct DD4 : public D2 {};
```

I have this abstract factory code:

```
//abstract factory version 1

struct AbstractFactoryImpl
{
    virtual D1* CreateD1() = 0;
    virtual D2* CreateD2() = 0;
};

struct AbstractFactory : public AbstractFactoryImpl
{
    virtual D1* CreateD1() { return new D1; };
    virtual D2* CreateD2() { return new D2; };
};

template<class ... Ts>
struct ConcreteFactory :public AbstractFactory
{
    using params = std::tuple<Ts...>;
    using T1 = typename std::tuple_element_t<0, params>;
    using T2 = typename std::tuple_element_t<1, params>;

    virtual D1* CreateD1()override
    {
        static_assert(std::is_base_of_v<D1, T1>);
        return new T1;
    };
    virtual D2* CreateD2()override
    {
        static_assert(std::is_base_of_v<D2, T2>);
        return new T2;
    };
};
```

And using it in client code like this.

```
//version 1
    AbstractFactory* pFactory;
    pFactory = new ConcreteFactory<DD1, DD3>;
    D1* pD1 = pFactory->CreateD1();
    D2* pD2 = pFactory->CreateD2();

    pFactory = new ConcreteFactory<DD2, DD4>;
    pD1 = pFactory->CreateD1();
    pD2 = pFactory->CreateD2();
```

It works  what i want and looks like a big part of examples in internet.

But in this version of abstract factorys if i want to add more classes in heirarchy(D3,DD5,DD6...) i must create too much code manually so i want to make code more generic.

```
//abstract factory version 2
template<typename T>
struct AbstractFactoryImpl_
{
    virtual T* Create() = 0;
};

template<typename T>
struct AbstractFactory_ :public AbstractFactoryImpl_<T>
{
    virtual T* Create() override
    {
        return new T;
    }
};

template<class ...Ts>
struct ConcreteFactory_ : public AbstractFactory_<Ts>...
{
    using params = std::tuple<Ts...>;
    using T1 = typename std::tuple_element_t<0, params>;
    using T2 = typename std::tuple_element_t<1, params>;

    template<class T>
    T* Create()
    {
        if constexpr (std::is_base_of_v<T, T1>)return AbstractFactory_<T1>::Create();
        else if constexpr (std::is_base_of_v<T, T2>)return AbstractFactory_<T2>::Create();

    }
};
```

And it works in client code like this:

```
        //version 2
    //AbstractFactory* pFactory; -- can`t use because AbstractFactory in version 2 is template class.
    auto pFactory_1 = new ConcreteFactory_<DD1, DD3>;
    D1* pD1_ = pFactory_1->Create<D1>();
    D2* pD2_ = pFactory_1->Create<D2>();

    auto pFactory_2 = new ConcreteFactory_<DD2, DD4>;
    pD1_ = pFactory_2->Create<D1>();
    pD2_ = pFactory_2->Create<D2>();
```

So it works but i must create two different pointers(`pFactory_1`,`pFactory_2`) to different instances of `ConcreteFactory_`. This is what not expected from Abstract Factory.
In first version it was ok because of virtual enheritance to call `Create` on Base class pointer. But here i have template base class. So i cant call on it pointer `Create()`.
So the question is how to make pointer or something else may be std::any o std::variant to make it possible in this Abstract Factory class design? The client code i wanna make to work is same like first version.

```
    TYPE* pFactory_ = new ConcreteFactory_<DD1, DD3>;
    D1* pD1_ = pFactory_->Create<D1>();
    D2* pD2_ = pFactory_->Create<D2>();

    auto pFactory_ = new ConcreteFactory_<DD2, DD4>;
    pD1_ = pFactory_->Create<D1>();
    pD2_ = pFactory_->Create<D2>();
```

Full code:
[https://cppinsights.io/s/552bbe01]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With some changes you might have:

```
// Way to "pass" Type.
template <typename T> struct Tag{};

template <typename T>
struct AbstractFactory
{
    virtual ~AbstractFactory() = default;
    virtual std::unique_ptr<T> Create(Tag<T>) const = 0;
};

template <typename ... Ts>
struct AbstractFactories : virtual AbstractFactory<Ts>...
{
    using AbstractFactory<Ts>::Create ...;
};

template <typename T, typename T2>
struct ConcreteFactory : virtual AbstractFactory<T>
{
    std::unique_ptr<T> Create(Tag<T>) const override { return std::make_unique<T2>(); }
};

template <typename Base, typename ...Ts>
struct ConcreteFactories;

template <typename ... Ts1, typename ...Ts2>
struct ConcreteFactories<AbstractFactories <Ts1...>, Ts2...> : AbstractFactories <Ts1...>, ConcreteFactory<Ts1, Ts2>...
{
    using ConcreteFactory<Ts1, Ts2>::Create ...;
};
```

With usage

```
void Test(AbstractFactories<D1, D2>& factory)
{
    std::unique_ptr<D1> d1 = factory.Create(Tag<D1>{});
    std::unique_ptr<D2> d2 = factory.Create(Tag<D2>{});
    // ...
}

int main()
{
    ConcreteFactories<AbstractFactories<D1, D2>, DD1, DD3> factory1;
    ConcreteFactories<AbstractFactories<D1, D2>, DD2, DD4> factory2;
    
    Test(factory1);
    Test(factory2);
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/189af3d4004ddd3c)

Comment: Wow. This is super generic. Just add new hierarchy element without changing factory at all. Is there any link where abstract factory like this discussing some source or more examples?

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be to add an alias into your concrete classes.

The advantage of this solution is that it keeps the syntax you wanted:

```
struct B {}; 

struct D1 : B {};
struct DD1 : D1 {
    using overrides = D1;
};
struct DD2 : D1 {
    using overrides = D1;
};

struct D2 : B {};
struct DD3 : D2 {
    using overrides = D2;
};
struct DD4 : D2 {
    using overrides = D2;
};
```

Then, simply change your `AbstractFactory_` type to this:

```
template<typename T>
struct AbstractFactoryImpl_
{
    virtual std::unique_ptr<T> Create() = 0;
};

template<typename T>
struct AbstractFactory_ : AbstractFactoryImpl_<typename T::overrrides>
{
    auto Create() -> std::unique_ptr<typename T::overrrides> override
    {
        return std::make_unique<T>();
    }
};
```

Using this, your code will simply work:

```
auto pFactory1 = ConcreteFactory_<DD1, DD3>{};
std::unique_ptr<D1> pD1_ = pFactory_.Create<D1>();
std::unique_ptr<D2> pD2_ = pFactory_.Create<D2>();

auto pFactory2 = ConcreteFactory_<DD2, DD4>{};
pD1_ = pFactory_.Create<D1>();
pD2_ = pFactory_.Create<D2>();
```

> So the question is how to make pointer or something else may be std::any o std::variant to make it possible in this Abstract Factory class design? The client code i wanna make to work is same like first version.

Don't do that. If you use pointer and inheritance for polymorphism, I'd advise not to mix other utility. For example, if you choose to return a `std::any`, you will have two layer of indirection: the any class, then the pointer. And to actually use the pointer, you will have to cast it to the right type, making the inheritance based indirection useless.

If you want to return `std::any`, go full `std::any` and always cast to the right type and skip the inheritance altogether. If you want to use `std::variant`, remove the inheritance and skip the virtual stuff and simply put all your types in the variant.

Looking at your inheritance structure, it's indeed a deep one (multiple level of inheritance). The solution would be to have a `BFactory` that has a pure virtual function returning a pointer to `B` and make all your factories extend from it.

It will add casts in your code, almost everywhere. Also, you repeat yourself, since you have to repeat the whole inheritance structure in your factory classes.

At this point, I would simply use type erasure instead. Instead of a deep, complex hierarchy of factories, I would use a generic type, concrete, that change its behavior depending on what you construct it with. You can roll your own, but you can also use one provided by the standard library. The simplest is `std::function`:

```
struct ClassThatNeedToMakeD1 {
    std::function<std::unique_ptr<D1>()> makeD1;

    void stuff() {
        auto myD1ptr = makeD1();
    }
};

int main() {
    auto myClass = ClassThatNeedToMakeD1{
        []{ return std::make_unique<DD2>(); }
    };

    myClass.stuff();
}
```

This stays simple, extensible and will do what you want at the places you want. Instead of coupling the construction strategy of all the `B` subclasses into a hierarchy of classes, you simply assign wanted behavior at the places that need that type erased factory function.

If you don't want to use `std::function`, you can roll your own limited equivalent:

```
template<typename T>
struct AnyFactory {
    template<typename Function>
    AnyFactory(Function f) : _factory{std::make_unique<Concrete<Function>>(std::move(f))} {}

    auto operator()() const -> std::unique_ptr<T> {
        return _factory->create();
    }

private:
    struct Abstract {
        virtual ~Abstract() = default;
        virtual auto create() const -> std::unique_ptr<T> = 0;
    };

    template<typename Function>
    struct Concrete : Abstract {
        Concrete(Function c) noexcept : _create{std::move(c)} {}

        auto create() const -> std::unique_ptr<T> override {
            return _create();
        }

        Function _create;
    };

    // Copy on write. The const is very important, don't remove it.
    // If you want to remove the const, change to unique_ptr + clone function in Abstract
    std::shared_ptr<const Abstract> _factory;
};

struct ClassThatNeedToMakeD1 {
    AnyFactory<D1> makeD1;

    void stuff() {
        auto myD1ptr = makeD1();
    }
};
 
int main() {
    // Usage stays the same
    auto myClass = ClassThatNeedToMakeD1{
        []{ return std::make_unique<DD2>(); }
    };

    myClass.stuff();
}
```

Small suggestions:

- Use `std::unique_ptr<T>` instead of `T*`, and `std::make_unique<T>()` instead of `new T`. I applied it in my answer.
- When using structs, you don't need `public` in inheritance. Structs inherit publicly by default.
- When you add the `override` keyword, don't put `virtual`. This is redundant.

Comment: Thank you for such detailed answer.  Using overrides here its new trick for me. Can u clarify about using type erasure with std::function? I see its like psudo code but i dont understand what type will have `myClass` after ctor recieve std::unique_ptr<DD2> ? It still be ClassThatNeedToMakeD1? So where the type erasure here? How it can decrease the volume of code writing if i need to create new variable and new classToMakeD2... At least this is how I understood the "meaning" of all these patterns.

Comment: @AlexeyChicherin The type of `myClass` is simply `ClassThatNeedToMakeD1`. I usualy put the type on the right side of the variable names, it's a coding style and it reads better in my opinion. It is not pseudocode, [it compiles and run](https://godbolt.org/z/5ze9s174K). The thing I send to the  `myClass` constructor is a lambda function. `[]` is the capture, the `()` that I omitted is the parameters, and the `{}` is the implementation. As you can see, it's perfect for the factory.

Comment: The type erasure is require since all lambda expressions all have their own distinct types. `std::function` is a type erasure utility that can contain any type of callable type like function pointer or lambda expressions.

Comment: There, [I removed all auto for the correct type here](https://godbolt.org/z/hEEnnMz7Y)

Comment: @AlexeyChicherin The thing that changed the most is instead of implementing complex factory classes, I added a `std::function` in the class that needs it. The manual type erasure also [compiles and run](https://godbolt.org/z/36oav9qfG). As you can see, instead of creating complex class hierarchy, the polymorphism is hidden inside `AnyFactory` and templated instead of done manually.

Comment: I see, it works. But this is just a way to encapsulate with specifiing every class. I might as well write `void f(D1* p){};` and `D1* p= new DD2;f(p);` . And if i want to follow defenition "The abstract factory pattern provides a way to encapsulate a group of individual factories that have a common theme without specifying their concrete classes." And following the idea of the author of the book that when adding new members of the hierarchy by the client, it is advisable not to add extra code, then this is entirely not Abstract Factory.